# How can I run a VB program on Windows XP without administrator privileges or .NET framework?

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework, visual-studio

I am able to run portable programs but i can't install anything. I have no permissions to install .NET framework.
My user connects at logon but usually I only work on one PC.

I write little programs in visual studio 2010 and 2012.
What can I do to make my programs run similar to the portable apps? Perhaps a different programming language?

Comment: May be these posts will give you some insight about running VB.NET app as portable app ... http://portableapps.com/node/12538 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110704/can-net-application-be-converted-into-a-portable-app-i-e-single-exe or http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/158806-how-to-make-a-vbnet-application-portable/ ...in short it looks like bit difficult to archive it.

Comment: If the system does not have .NET Framework then the user will be unable to use the application written in a .NET Language.  **Once the .NET Framework is installeed creating a portable .NET application is trivial.**

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be suitable for you, but instead of writing applications targetting .NET in Visual Studio, write native C++ applications instead. When you target the vX of the .NET framework, then the application will require that the targetted framework version is installed.